# Update a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns, I have to update a column with `true` or `false` based on a condition. Example the column names are `price` and `result`, if `price` column has `promotion` as value then result column should be updated as `true` or else `false`.

Please help me with this.

Comment: `df[result].apply(lambda x: x==promotion value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this df:

```
       price  result
0  promotion       0
1          1       0
2          4       0
3          3       0
```

You can do so:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['price'] == 'promotion', True, False)
```

Output:

```
      price  result
0  promotion    True
1          1   False
2          4   False
3          3   False
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose the dataframe looks like this:

```
    price     result
0   0          False
1   1          False
2   2          False
3   promotion  False
4   3          False
5   promotion  False
```

You can create two boolean arrays. The first one will have 'True' value at the indices where you want to set the 'True' value in result column and the second one will have 'True' values at the indices where you want to set 'False' value in result column.
Here is the code:

```
index_true = (df['price'] == 'promotion')
index_false = (df['price'] != 'promotion')

df.loc[index_true, 'result'] = True
df.loc[index_false, 'result'] = False
```

The resultant dataframe will look like this:

```
    price   result
0   0        False
1   1        False
2   2        False
3   promotion   True
4   3        False
5   promotion   True
```